# Getting a weird validation error with mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

*bug*

Hello guys, i'm facing with a weird error with mongoose. 
I'm trying to make a post request to add a product with angular js but i'm getting a 404 error. 
In my google chrome console, the error said that :

```
{"data":
{"errors":{"picture":
{"message":"Path `picture` is required.",
"name":"ValidatorError","properties":
{"type":"required","message":"Path `{PATH}` is 
required.","path":"picture"},"kind":"required","path":"picture"},
"name":{"message":"Path `name` is 
 required.","name":"ValidatorError","properties":
{"type":"required","message":"Path `{PATH}` is     
required.","path":"name"},"kind":"required","path":"name"}},
"message":"Product validation 
failed","name":"ValidationError"}
```

When i'm using postman client the post request works fine. But not with angular js. So i want to know how i can fix this issue. I really need help

Here you can find my product model script

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {type: String, required: true}, 
category: {type: String, default: ''}, 
price: { type: Number, default: 0}, 
    picture: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true},  
    morePictures: [mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed], 
    quantity: {type: Number, default: 0}, 
    status: { 
    type: String, 
    enum: ['Pending', 'In Progress', 'Cancelled', 'Done'], 
    default: 'Pending' 
    }, 
   date: { type: Date, default: Date.now}, 
   description: { type: String}, 
    owner: {type: String}
   }); 

 var Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema); 

 module.exports = Product;
```

My Product Controller where i define my actions to diferent routes.

```
module.exports.createProduct = function (req, res){
  var product = new Product(req.body); 
   console.log(req.body); 
   product.save( function (err, newProduct){
     if(err){
        return sendJsonResponse(res, 404, err); 
    }
    else 
        return sendJsonResponse(res, 201, newProduct);
 })
}
```

````
and in my angular js script where i define my addProduct method

```
app.controller('ProductController', ['$scope','$http','filepickerService', 
function ($scope, $http, filepickerService){
    console.log('Welcome to the ProductController'); 

    *** some code here ***
    $scope.addProduct = function (){ 

        var newProduct = {
            name: $scope.product.name, 
            category: $scope.product.category, 
            price: $scope.product.price, 
            picture: $scope.product.picture, 
            morePictures: [], 
            quantity: 10,  
            status: "Pending", 
            date: Date.now(), 
            description: $scope.product.description, 
            owner: "Joel Alexandre Khang Zulbal"
        }; 

        console.log(newProduct); 
        alert("Passing variable..."); 

        $http({
                url: '/api/products', 
                method: 'POST', 
                 headers: {
                       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                     },
                data: newProduct
            })
             .then( function onSuccessCallback (products){
                    $scope.products.push(products);
                        alert("Success Insertion");
                 }, function onErrorCallback (error){
                        console.log(error); 
                        alert("Insertion failed!!"); 
                 }); 

            $scope.product = {}; 
            $scope.close(); 
    }
       *** some other code here ***
}]);
```

I don't know how to fix that, any help will be verry gratefull.

```
node version: 6.9.4
mongodb version: 3.4.4
mongoose version: 4.8.1 
OS: Windows 10
```

Here the error i get when using angular js [Mongoose error validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRYa4.jpg)

Here my newProduct object when i'm make a post request with angularjs [Mongoose error angular js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS7bF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Please read your error log carefully.
It shows that you have not set value for `picture` and `name`.

Both of them is required. Please input them to your POST request or remove `required` if unnecessary.

Comment: So that's the problem when i'm using Postman i'm setting a value for both of them. The same in angularjs but it doesn't work. When i remove required for picture and name when i'm making a post request with angularjs, The post request succeed but an empty object is saved instead even if I set all the value when making that request... 

Comment: Could you send me a screenshot of Postman? I don't think that it's the Postman issue.

Comment: With postman i don't have any problem everything work as excepted but not with angularjs

Comment: Could you log and share newProduct value, please?

Comment: I think you see my newProduct value... Even in my controller where i create a new product with mongoose i make a console.log(req.body) just to see if any value was passed and i can see that the value was passed... So I don't know what's the problem

Comment: @JoelAlexandreKhang Have you checked `var product = new Product(req.body);`? What is the value of `picture` and `name`?

Comment: It's exactly the same value I passed when I making a post request with angularjs. It's crazy! doesn't it?

Comment: It's too strange ... :(

Comment: Too strange like you said... 